# Detect URL redirect path php

Tags: php, curl

I want to get full redirect path of the url.

Let's say if source.com redirects to destination.com after multiple redirects like this:
http://www.source.com/ -> http://www.b.com/ -> http://www.c.com/ -> http://www.destination.com/

how do I get all redirected URL's?

using this below code I am getting only http://www.destination.com/ how do I detect full url redirect chain?

```
<?php
$url='windows.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // no needs to pass the headers to the data stream
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // get the resource without a body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // accept any server certificate
curl_exec($ch);

// get the last used URL
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

      curl_close($ch);

   echo $lastUrl;
?>
```

This code has another problem it can't detect redirected url of youtube redirects.
Tested URL : `https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=QUFFLUhqbkVxUFZUME9NbWF4RThxdFpGV3pmTTJEdFVWQXxBQ3Jtc0tubGJqU016TzJ6WnlfeUItX0ZmOUItUE1jRlZoZXhxMzNpQllpM0NLSk4ycnBLMGNidTFsX3N6WkU2X3RsUTRZb1lXQVp5SEZjbnU3eDFuZS1VU3dhdzg2QW9ZMTl1azFCZFZHcHRLdFF3dTM1MlRWdw%3D%3D&event=video_description&v=KEa2XWRGf_4&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fabhiandniyu`

My question is how do I detect full url redirect chain for all types of redirect requests.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Writing plain cURL commands bloats your code a lot, so why not use some library like Guzzle?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
```

add it to your CURL config and it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't follow HTTP redirects: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`

And output HTTP headers, while testing: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`

Then you can obtain the `Location` header from the received `HTTP 302` response.

When it's more than one redirect, this would have to run in a loop, until `HTTP 200` has been received. In this context `HTTP 200` means, that the final destination has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curl_getinfo() function in PHP to get information about the last transfer. This includes the total redirect count and an array of all the URLs in the redirect path. Here's an example:

```
$url = 'http://www.source.com/';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);

$redirectCount = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT);
$redirectUrlList = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);

echo "Total redirects: $redirectCount\n";
echo "Redirect URL list: \n";
print_r($redirectUrlList);
```

This will output something like:

```
Total redirects: 3
Redirect URL list:
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.b.com/
    [1] => http://www.c.com/
    [2] => http://www.destination.com/
)
```

You can then use this information to track the full redirect path.

Or, you can use various tools like RedirHub's redirect checker at https://www.redirhub.com/tool/redirect-checker. This tool allows you to enter a URL and see if it redirects, and if so, how many times it redirects and the final destination URL